# ValueError when trying to separate training and test set

Tags: python, statistics

I've tried the following code in python:

```
X=df[["age","bmi","children"]].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y=df["charges"].values.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
X_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = X_scaler.fit_transform(X)
Y = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2136, 712]
```

If I do it without the reshape it gives me:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

So I don't know what to do
If someone can help me I will appreciate it

Comment: add dataset in your question

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a solution, I've changed Y:

```
Y = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

And it worked